# How to display an activity over the lock screen?

Tags: android, service, lockscreen

I know an activity will get killed when the screen is locked. So wanna use service i guess. how to display an activity or ring a sound over the lock screen by pressing power button twice? I tried many questions related to it here but i don't find solution at all.
Here is the question I posted before.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242776/toast-is-not-displayed-over-the-lock-screen

Answer (score 0):

to show your Activity on lock screen you need to register reciever for off/on screen, then in `onReceive()` method start your activity on lock screen and keep screen on and ... .
see this  [Link](https://github.com/ShakeebM/Android-LockScreen/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/shakeeb/customlockscreen/LockScreenAppActivity.java)  . it should help you.

Comment: kindly see the code I posted in the above question's link

Answer (score 0):

```
call this method at your Activity onCreate()

public void aboveLockScreen() {
          Window window = getWindow();
          window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    }
```

Comment: add some explanation in your answer

Comment: put this method at your Class and just call to this method at oncreate() method if you won't to open your activity above the lock screen.